# Missing 64 bit support,when uploading titanium app on appstore

Tags: titanium

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "AppName". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.
After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
Regards,
The App Store team

Its saying to change the build setting of xcode,but the app has been created on titanium,so how to change the settings in titanium so that it has 64  bit support,in my titanium project ,I have no  .xcodeproj file,so how I will convert titanium 32 bit into 64 bit ob xcode..???

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 3.5.0 SDK Titanium and Xcode 6.1.1 to build apps to support ios8.
You need to update the modules to 64-bit if they were in 32-bit. Below is the link for the modules which are converted to 64-bit.
http://gitt.io/search?q=%20architectures%3Ax86_64